# How to assure contract with multiple classes that are similar in behavior but different in implementation?

Tags: c#

The simplest example I can think of to illustrate this question involves two logger classes.

In this example, LoggerA and LoggerB both implement an ILogger interface to achieve polymorphism.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void SomeMethodBNeeds;
    void LogB;
    bool LogA;
}

public class LoggerA : ILogger
{
    public void SomeMethodBNeeds()
    {
        // Do nothing; un-needed here.
    }

    public bool LogA()
    {
        // Perform some work.
    }

    public void LogB()
    {
        LogA();
    }
}

public class LoggerB : ILogger
{
    public void SomeMethodBNeeds()
    {
        // Perform some work.
    }

    public bool LogA()
    {
        LogB();
        return true;
    }

    public void LogB()
    {
        // Perform some work.
    }
}
```

Since ILogger is an interface, both LoggerA and LoggerB need to implement every method, even if LoggerA does not need `SomeMethodBNeeds`. As such `SomeMethodBNeeds` is empty and does nothing in LoggerA.

The same applies to the LogA and LogB methods; they are different, but both needed and used in certain places. In this case, they both achieve the same thing, but have different method signatures, as such I am just calling one from the other to "tie up loose ends".

There is then a third owning class that achieves the polymorphism, and needs to be the one to call these methods.

```
class SomeOwningClass : SomeOwningBaseClass
{
    ILogger myLogger;

    #if DEBUG
        myLogger = new LoggerA();
    #else
        myLogger = new LoggerB();
    #endif

    protected override void ProgramLaunched()
    {
        myLogger.SomeMethodBNeeds();
    }

    protected override void ProgramStopped()
    {
    }

    protected override void ProgramResumed()
    {
        myLogger.SomeMethodBNeeds();
    }

    protected override void ProgramPaused()
    {
    }   
}
```

Obviously this should throw a number of red flags at any good developer since it seems the interface is not being used as was intended. If this behavior was intended you wouldn't have to implement every function in the interface, and you wouldn't be simply calling one of the `Log` methods from the other or throwing not-implemented exceptions.

The next thing someone would then think is to use an abstract class, however, LoggerA and LoggerB really do not share code, so would that constitute proper use of an Abstract class?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Makoto it is C# but the language is irrelevant. The topic is about CS principles dealing with inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: There may be something language-specific which helps get a few conceptual hurdles out of the way, which is why I asked.  You also provided more than pseudocode (at first glance).

Comment: well, what is the reason for having two different method name? why it can't be just using `Log()` or something.. i thought it was the reason for interface no? oh well, perhaps [virtual keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) will interest you - language specific though.

Comment: @BagusTesa Inheritance, and therefore the virtual keyboard is intended to be used in "is-a" relationships. In this case LoggerB is not a LoggerA and therefore violates Liskovs' Substitutionality Principle and is not suitable for inheritance.

Comment: Without knowing more about what's *actually* going on here, we can't really suggest appropriate designs for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Polymorphism is not at issue here

Polymorphism occurs when the base implementation calls a derived method.  It is therefore not possible with interface inheritance, which has no implementation inheritance.

One way to remember what polymorphism means... A developer can write a base class in the year 2005, and years later a developer can write a derived class that modifies some of its behavior.  Thus the original code *morphs* into a new behavior even though it was never touched.  The capabilities of the base class polymorph as more and more derived classes are added.

In a way, polymorphism means the base class has an (internal) interface it can rely on.  This is different from implementing an *external* interface, which is not a promise to the base class but is instead a promise to calls originating outside of the class.

### Interfaces are a promise to the caller

An interface is a contract with the caller.  When you add an interface to a class, you promise to support that the interface implies.  Only methods that are promised should be included; methods like `SomeMethodBNeeds` should not be included in that contract.  Only include methods that are needed *by the caller*, not by other classes that implement the interface.

### The NotImplementedException

In exceptional cases, it's OK to include in the interface things that are not always implemented.  A good example, is the ApplyDispatchBehavior method of the IEndpointBehavior interface; this interface can implemented for the client, server, or both.  If it's client-only, the ApplyDispatchBehavior isn't needed, and should therefore be coded to throw a `NotImplementedException` (see [Microsoft's recommendation to do so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.applydispatchbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) in this case).

### In your case

Just remove `SomeMethodANeeds` and `SomeMethodBNeeds` from the interface definition.  That way, class A can still call SomeMethodANeeds (it knows about it, because it's in its own class) and class B can still call SomeMethodBNeeds, but the caller won't know how to call those (and shouldn't need to) from just the interface.  I would also suggest thatboth SomeMethodANeeds and SomeMethodBNeeds be scoped private or protected-- which means they can't be in the interface to begin with, since interface methods have to be public.

Now perhaps you are in a situation where you can't remove one of those methods because you need some way to pass a class-specific argument to a method.  For example, if you have a `FlatFileLogger` and a `SQlLogger`, perhaps the SqlLogger needs a connection string while the FlatFileLogger does not.  If that is the case, you've designed the interface improperly.  **An interface should be usable by any caller without any knowledge of the implementation of the class that implements the interface.**

That being said, you could always cheat, like this:

```
ILogger _logger = GetLogger();  //Might be any type of Logger
SqlLogger sqlLogger = _logger as SqlLogger;  //Try to get class-specific interface
if (sqlLogger != null)  //Logger is in fact a SqlLogger
{
    sqlLogger.SetConnectionString(AppConfig.LoggerConnectionString); //Call method not in interface
}
_logger.Log("Logger started.");  //Using class-agnostic interface to actually log data
```

^I see stuff like this around a lot, but it sort of defeats the purpose of having a common interface.  The code of course will not be forward compatible with other classes that implement the interface if they need class-specific logic.  To maintain separation of concerns, perhaps the class-specific logic should be moved to the factory method, like this:

```
ILogger GetLogger()  //Factory method.  Uses config to determine what sort of ILogger to return.
{
    if (AppConfig.UseFlatFileLogger) return new FlatFileLogger();
    if (AppConfig.UseSqlLogger )
    {
        SqlLogger sqlLogger = new SqlLogger();
        sqlLogger.SetConnectionString(GetLoggerConnectionString()); //Call method not in interface
        return sqlLogger;
    }
    throw new ConfigurationException("Logger type not supported.");
{

//Main program.  Notice 100% of this code is class-agnostic.
ILogger _logger = GetLogger();  
_logger.Log("Logger started.");
```

### TL;DR

There is no rule that says all of a class' methods need to be in the interface.  You can leave the method in the class but leave it out of the interface.  If you literally *can't* do that (because the caller needs the class-specific methods too) then you have designed your interface improperly.

Comment: Thanks for outlining the difference between polymorphism and interfaces. Part of the issue that I don't see you have addressed is that `SomeMethodANeeds` and `SomeMethodBNeeds` are not only needed by A and B, but they are needed by the caller. Such methods call other private methods in `A` and `B`. These methods also need to be called from within an inherited method in the owning class, within the `ProgramLaunched()`, `ProgramResumed()`, etc methods.

Comment: I think this may be one of those situations where `NotImplementedException` would be a decent solution, because otherwise you would need `SomeOwningClass` to implement some interface where the logger would be assured `SomeOwningClass` will raise some event `OnProgramLaunched` `OnProgramResumed`, etc and I think this would increase the coupling between `SomeOwningClass` and the logger too much. Logger would cease to be this reusable component and rather be tightly coupled to this specific code.

Comment: I provided code examples showing how to call a class-specific method without needing to include it in the interface.  If the interface can't be changed, and there are methods in the interface that are not supported by every class that implements it, then the classes that do not support the method should throw the `NotImplementedException`.  Alternatively, the class could fail silently and return success, e.g. if the purpose of the method is to pass information that the class can safely ignore.

Comment: While I see your point, I don't think you have fully addressed the actual question, yet. Your factory method works in the situation you outlined, but is not ideal in the situation I described. Take for instance, that in my situation, you would have to perform these cast checks in multiple places to call methods specific to the type of Logger. One could argue that it is easier to have a contract where you call `SomeMethodBNeeds` regardless of the type of Logger. Such method would simply do nothing if Logger is of type `LoggerA`, or the appropriate work if the Logger is of type `LoggerB`.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide specifics of what that call is supposed to do?  I could be wrong but it smells like you're not using interfaces properly (c.f. [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: Right. I tried to be as non-specific as possible in the hopes that people would focus on the issue, but I guess in this case, being more specific may shed more light into the issue.
In my case, `LoggerB` is an asynchronous logger that logs to a web server. Such logger needs to establish and end sessions to the web server whenever the program execution is started and ended.

Comment: `LoggerA` is a synchronous logger that pretty much just prints to `Debug.WriteLine` and some UI elements. So in my case, LogA is a synchronous method, while LogB is an asynchronous method.

The issue then is that, in order to avoid these type checks throughout the program, the solution was to implement this contract. Clearly it seems like an ugly solution and misuse of the contract, but possibly justified.

Comment: I'll add a second answer to address this case directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow SOLID principles. Specifically Interface Segregation Principle. So instead of forcing two of your classes implement same interface, separate that interface so that A does not need to implement method which B needs and vice versa.

More [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766045/Interface-Segregation-Principle-ISP-of-SOLID-in-Cs)

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogB();
    bool LogA();
}

public class LoggerA : ILogger
{
    public bool LogA()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void LogB()
    {
        LogA();
    }
}

public class LoggerB : ILogger
{
    public bool LogA()
    {
        LogB();
        return true;
    }

    public void LogB()
    {
        // Perform some work.
    }
}

public interface ISomeMethod
{
    void SomeMethodBNeeds();
}

public class D : ISomeMethod
{
    public void SomeMethodBNeeds()
    {
        // Perform some work.
    }
}

class C
{
    ISomeMethod myLogger;
    public C()
    {
        myLogger = new D();
    }

    protected void ProgramLaunched()
    {
        myLogger.SomeMethodBNeeds();
    }

    protected void ProgramStopped()
    {
    }

    protected void ProgramResumed()
    {
        myLogger.SomeMethodBNeeds();
    }

    protected void ProgramPaused()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds simple enough in theory, but look at the code presented, the owning class would need special checks to determine what kind of Logger `myLogger` is to know whether to call `SomeMethodBNeeds`, which defeats the purpose of having the polymorphism in the first place.

Comment: Your example is flawed, if you instantiate `myLogger` as `D` then you can never call `LogA` or `LogB`...

Comment: I guess I didn't make it clear that both LogA and LogB need to be called at certain points by the owning class, in your case, `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow SOLID principles and also you need to learn the 4 pillars of Object Orientation (in this case Encapsulation).

A-man is right. However, he is missing the problem here.

Where as the OP is missing the point that there are many ways to skin a cat.

Your interface should do one thing and one thing well. Specifically Logging.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogA();
    bool LogB();
}
```

The fact that LoggerB needs to something else to complete it job is outside of the scope of the interface.

To give another example of an abstract class car.

```
public abstract class Engine {
    void PressAccelerator()
}
```

For the abstract car, we know that pressing the Accelerator makes the Speedometer go up.

Lets implement the car

```
public class PetrolEngine : Engine
{
    public void PressAccelerator()
    {
        this.InjectFuelInto(_engine);
    }
}
```

Okay. That seems simple.

But what about the Hybrid car?

```
public class HybridEngine : Engine
{
    private IBattery _battery;

    private bool HasElectricCharge()
    {
        return _battery.HasCharge();
    }

    public void PressAccelerator()
    {
        if(HasElectricCharge())
            this.PumpElectronsInto(_electricMotor);
        else
            this.InjectFuelInto(_engine);
    }
}
```

What we have done here is called Encapsulation. We have hidden the complexity of the HybridEngine from the IEngine interface.

My advice, in your case.

Either have LoggerB have an `eventhandler` which respond to `MyProgram.Started` and `MyProgram.Stopped` or perhaps `MyProgram.RunStateChanged`.

Or....you inject `MyProgram` into `LoggerB` and have `LoggerB` query `MyProgram.RunState`.

Comment: I am so confused as to your example... It's missing a lot and also avoids the two issues. As per your advice, you are introducing tight coupling between the logger class and MyProgram that would really overcomplicate and confuse users of such class. You would be forcing MyProgram to have a RunState variable, and events to signal updating, you would be forcing the logger to have a reference to the class, and other unnecessarily complicated issues. MyProgram should be using the Logger, not the other way around.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera You were the one that introduced a tight coupling between MyProgram and LoggerB. However, you can loosen the coupling with an interface on `MyProgram`. The fact is, LoggerB "listens" on `MyProgram". So you really should have `MyProgram` instanciate `LoggerB` and then attach itself to `LoggerB.OnRunStateChanged` eventhandler. Personally I would have LoggerB take a `IApplicationState` in the constructor, whilst `MyProgram : IApplicationState`.

Comment: could you provide a complete, minimal, code example using the loggers, if that is ok? I think you may be on to something, however, I cannot tell If there is an issue.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera I could do...I show you mine, if you show me yours (I need a less abstract understanding of your problem)?

Answer (score 1):

## Dealing with the specific case

### Requirements

Based on the comments I infer the following requirements:

1. Logger must be callable from main code base without concern for underlying implementation
2. Some types of loggers require code to execute (e.g. establish a session on a web server that will receive logging data) before logging starts
3. Some types of loggers require code to execute when the program exits (e.g. close a session on a remote web server)

### Design

Here is how I would do it:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

class BasicLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message); //Or use whatever output method is suitable
    }
}

class StatefulLogger : ILogger, IDisposable
{
    public StatefulLogger()
    {
        StartSession();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndSession();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        EndSession();
    }

    private void StartSession()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Logger session started.");
        //Do Stuff
    }

    private void EndSession()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit -= CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
        //Do stuff
        Console.WriteLine("Logger session ended.");
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

With the code above, programmers who wish to use the ILogger interface don't have to worry about the implementation of the logger, and the logger class will properly establish and tear down sessions without any intervention on their part.  This maintains separation of concerns and the integrity of the ILogger interface.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Here is a pastebin containing some of the code, it slightly differs from your code, but should be enough to give you a complete picture of the issue. http://pastebin.com/YJEkPMs0

Comment: May I suggest you submit this code to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?  Think there is an overall issue here of separation of concerns.  There is way too much code in the main program that is responsible for setting up the logger just right.

Comment: Code Review submitted here - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150527/proper-separation-of-concerns-for-stateful-logger